# Add a custom People Picker within a custom html web part?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In my custom web part, where I have imported the aspx file, I am creating a form to allow users to add items to a list much easier. I have added this following code to my page:

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="PeopleEditor1" runat="server" AllowEmpty="true" MultiSelect="true" SelectionSet="User" />
```

Though, when I save the file and refresh the page, the element isn't on the page. When I use the web tools (on Chrome) and look at the actual html code, the `SharePoint:PeopleEditor` is there.

I honestly not too familiar with ASP or SharePoint development, so I'm not sure what the sure of the problem is, which makes it hard what to ask. Hopefully, someone has some good insight.

NOTE: I'm working with Sharepoint 2010 CMOS.

EDIT: My goal is have something like this in my form:
[image: MS Sharepoint people picker example]

We already have a database of people in our system that works with the people picker in the other areas of Sharepoint that uses it. I want to be able to use this same thing inside my form inside my custom web part. I want to be able to add people with the people picker within my form.

Comment: I think browser should not show "SharePoint:PeopleEditor" because browser does not know what is sharepoint. It should show some input box or some div. Please try to elaborate what you are actually want to do?

Comment: I want to be able to use the people picker inside my custom form that's inside my custom web part.